# Developing with rosjava in Android Studio (Windows)

Tags: ros, windows, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to develop a simple Android which is supposed to show some stats of a robot on the smartphone. I'd like to to this on a windows computer, and if I'm not mistaken that should be possible. However, I know little to nothing about ROS and just have basic knowledge of Android Studio. Furthermore, I found no decent tutorial on what I need to do (either not working and/or outdated). Does someone know some good tutorial or can help me getting started? Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276678/developing-with-rosjava-in-android-studio-(windows)/) by [Kubi](https://answers.ros.org/users/32641/kubi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-11-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @Kubi, it *may* work if you don't need to create any new message or service.

You will need to update your Gradle script to add the Maven repository for rosjava [rosjava_mvn_repo](http://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_mvn_repo). Then, you should be able to add the core depencies for rosjava and ros Android.

Check http://wiki.ros.org/android/Tutorials/kinetic/Installation%20-%20Android%20Studio%20Development%20Environment and http://wiki.ros.org/rosjava/Tutorials/kinetic/No%20Ros%20Installation for reference. I've never tried using that on Windows myself, but in general terms using ROSJava and ROSAndroid should be possible after adding the core dependencies to your buildscripts.

---

Originally posted by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) with karma: 1054 on 2017-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kubi](https://answers.ros.org/users/32641/kubi/) on 2017-12-06**:
Thanks for the answer! I eventually ended up working on Ubuntu, but the tutorials you linked apply anyways, right? I just dont understand how to upgrade rosjava_mvn_rep...?

**Comment by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) on 2017-12-06**:
Yes; in fact I wouldn't recommend using Windows. I'd suggest you to install rosjava from source; it doesn't take that long. The tutorials already set your buildscripts to point to rosjava_mvn_repo, where the core artifacts are.
If you want to add your own artifacts, that's another story.

**Comment by [サイトダニエロ](https://answers.ros.org/users/54834/%E3%82%B5%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88%E3%83%80%E3%83%8B%E3%82%A8%E3%83%AD/) on 2020-05-13**:
I'm trying to do this on windows, still don't understand too much, to be honest I'm 90% lost